# Question about polar decomposition. Is the book wrong?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras

An introduction to the classification of amenable C*-algebra.

page 140 Lemma 3.5.1 Let $x\in A$ with the polar decomposition $x=u|x|$ in $A''$ and $B=\overline{x^*Ax}$. Then $ub\in B$ for every $b\in B$.

$A''$ refers to the enveloping C*-algebra of $A$, the weak closure of $A$ in $B(H)$ where $A$ is universally represented. But these are not important.

Let $A$ be $B(l^2(\mathbb N))$ and let $x$ be the shift operator such that $x(e_j)=e_{j-1}$. Then $\overline {x^*Ax}=B(0\oplus l^2(\mathbb N^+))$ (regarding $B(0\oplus l^2(\mathbb N^+))$ as a subalgebra of $B(l^2(\mathbb N))$). Since $x$ is a partial isometry itself so $x=x|x|$ and $|x|$ is the projection onto $0\oplus l^2(\mathbb N^+)$.
However, $x=x|x|\not\in \overline{x^*Ax}$ since no element in $\overline{x^*Ax}=\overline{|x|A|x|}$ has range larger than $0\oplus l^2(\mathbb N^+)$.

Am I wrong, or is the book wrong?

Comment: Bear in mind that I really know next to nothing about $C^*$ algebras, but why are you expecting $x \in x^* A x$? The lemma says $ub \in B$ for every $b \in B$. If $e$ is the identity map in $A = B(\ell^2(\Bbb{N}))$, then $e \notin \overline{x^*Ax}$ for the same reason you stated, so I don't see why $x = xe$ ought to be in $\overline{x^* A x}$? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @user824599 maybe i should write more details. There is a fact that every C\* algebra contains an approximate unit and $\overline {x^*Ax} $ is actually called the hereditary C\* algebra generated by $x^*x$. Approximate is a net of elements $f_\lambda$ such that $f_\lambda x\to x$ holds for every $x$. This guarantees that $x^* f_\lambda x\to x^*x=|x|^2$ is always in $x^*Ax$. Then by the existence of square root, $|x|\in x^*Ax$. By hypothesis, $x|x|=x\in x^*Ax$.

Comment: @user824599 and in the example i gave, the projection $|x|$
onto $0\oplus B(l^2(\mathbb N^+))$ is in $x^*Ax$ which makes $x|x|\in x^*Ax$ according to the lemma.

Comment: I think Lin wanted the statement of that Lemma to say  "Then $ubu^* \in B$ for every $b \in B$" rather than "$ub \in B$".  At least, when he uses it in the proof of (3.5.3) in the next page, it seems that this is what he has in mind.

Comment: @Ruy Do you mean $ubu^∗∈B$  for every $b∈B$ ? Suppose you are right, note that $x^*Ax=|x|A|x|$ and $uBu^*=xAx^*$, it is still not true, since $x^*Ax= xAx^*$ does not always hold.

Comment: @Ruy The counterexample is still the same, let $x$ be the left shift operator then $x|x|x^*=id$ which is not in $x^*Ax$.

Comment: You are absolutely right and I am sorry for having misled you.  I guess the whole point is to try to salvage (3.5.1) in such a way that the application in (3.5.3) becomes lawful.  For that purpose it would be enough to show that if $b\in B$ then $ubu^*$ is in $A$ but I think in fact Lin's proof may be modified to show that if $b\in B$ then $ubu^*$ is in $\overline{xAx^*}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my impression that Lin wanted his Lemma to say:

**Lemma 3.5.1**. Let $x\in A$ with the polar decomposition $x=u|x|$ in $A''$.  Also let   $B_1=\overline{x^*Ax}$ and $B_2=\overline{xAx^*}$.
Then $uB_1u^*\subseteq B_2$.

Here is a proof of this result broken into Lemmas, each of which might have some interest in itself.

**Lemma 1**.  $x = \lim_n x(x^*x)^{1/n}$.

*Proof*.  Compute $\Vert x  - x(x^*x)^{1/n}\Vert ^2$ using the C*-identity $\Vert y\Vert ^2 = \Vert y^*y\Vert $.

**Lemma 2**.  For every $\alpha >0$ one has that $u(x^*x)^\alpha = (xx^*)^\alpha u\in A$.

*Proof*.  Since both sides vanish on the kernel of $x$ (seen in any  given faithful Hilbert space representation), it is enough to
show that they agree on
$$
  \text{Ker}(x)^\perp = \overline{\text{Ran}(x^*)} = \overline{ \text{Ran}(|x|)}.
  $$
We have
$$
  u(x^*x)^\alpha |x| =
  u|x| (x^*x)^\alpha =
  x (x^*x)^\alpha =
  (xx^*)^\alpha  x =
  (xx^*)^\alpha u|x|.
  $$

This proves the identity in the statement, so let us now prove that $u(x^*x)^\alpha \in A$.

Approximate the function $f(t)=t^{2\alpha}$ on the spectrum of $|x|$ by  a
polynomial  $p$ without constant term and hence we may write $p(t) = t q(t)$ for some other polynomial $q$.  Then
$$
  u(x^*x)^\alpha =
  u |x|^{2\alpha} \sim
  u p(|x|) =
  u |x| q(|x|) =
  x q(|x|) \in  A.
  $$
QED.

**Lemma 3**.  $ux^*\in  \overline{xA}$.

*Proof*.
$$
  ux^* =
  \lim_n u(x^*x)^{2/n}x^* =
  \lim_n (xx^*)^{1/n}u(x^*x)^{1/n}x^* \in 
  \overline{xA}.
  $$
QED

Therefore  the  result we need,  namely
$$
  ux^*Axu^* \subseteq  \overline{xAx^*}
  $$
follows easily.

Comment: By the way, do you know how to prove 1.11.44? I am having trouble on it...

Comment: Yes.     Lets go over to where you asked this question.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again... I have had trouble showing $b_1=bz_1b\geq 0$ in Lemma 3.5.8. Could you please give me some hint about it? I don't see why $g(|x|)$ and $d_1$ are commutative.

Comment: I think Huaxin made another mistake.  If you'd like to post this as a new question I'll have more room to describe a counter-example.

Comment: Lol ok let me post a new question. I hadn't thought it would be a mistake.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3833542/ here I have posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the book is wrong. It was supposed to be $ub \in A$ for all $b \in B$.

See also Farah's book Corollary 1.6.13.