# Question on tracial topological rank of C*-algebra and finite CW complex.

Tags: c-star-algebras, cw-complexes

Denote by $I^{(0)}$ the class of finite dimensional C*-algebras and by $I^{(k)}$ the class of unital C*-algebras which are unital hereditary C*-subalgebras of C*-algebras of the form $C(X)\otimes F$ where $X$ is a $k$-dimensional finite CW complex and $F\in I^{(0)}$ .

For a unital simple C*-algebra $A$, write $TR(A)\leq k$ if for any $\epsilon>0$ ,finite set $F\subseteq A$, and $0\neq a\in A^+$, there exist a nonzero projection $p\in A$ and a C*-subalgebra $B\in I^{(k)}$ with $1_B=p$ such that:
$$\begin{align}
&(1)\|px-xp\|<\epsilon\text{ for all }x\in F\\&(2)\|pxp- B\|<\epsilon \text{ for all }x\in F\\&(3) 1-p\text{ is equivalent to a projection in Her}(a)\end{align}
$$

---

It was left as an excersice that unital simple inductive limit of $A_n$ with $TR(A_n)\leq k$ has tracial topological rank no more than $k$.

Since the only C*-subalgebras I can construct from the condition are the $\varphi_n(A_n)$, where $\varphi_n:A_n\to A$ are the canonical homomorphisms, I thought I need to show that $\varphi_n(A_n)$ are in $I^{(k)}$.

Fix one $n$, $A_n$ is a hereditary subalgebra of some algebra of form $C(X)\otimes F$. By the fact that every ideal of $A_n$ is of form $A_n\cap J$ for some ideal $J$ of $C(X)\otimes F$, I see that $A_n/\ker \varphi_n$ is a hereditary subalgebra of $(C(X)\otimes F)/J$.

However, $(C(X)\otimes F)/J$ is of form $C(Y_1)\otimes M_{n_1}\oplus ...\oplus C(Y_k)\otimes M_{n_k}$, where every $Y_j$ is a closed subset of $X$. To show $A_n/\ker(\varphi_n)$ is in $I^{(k)}$, I (maybe?) need to construct a $C(X')\otimes F'$ which contains $C(Y_1)\otimes M_{n_1}\oplus ...\oplus C(Y_k)\otimes M_{n_k}$ as a hereditary subalgebra, and I have no idea how to do this.

Also I do not know how do I use the simpleness of $A$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If $K\subseteq [0, 1]$ is the ternary Cantor set, then $C(K)$ is a quotient of $C([0,1])$, which in turn belongs to $I^{(1)}$.  However $C(K)$ is not in $I^{(1)}$ because $C(K)$ contains an infinite set of nonzero pairwise projections and this cannot happen in an algebra of the form $C(X) \otimes F$, where $X$ is a finite CW complex and the dimension of $F$ is finite.  This means that $I^{(1)}$ is not closed under quotients!

Comment: Actually notice that the quotient map $\varphi :C([0,1])\to C(K)$ may indeed show up as one of your $\varphi _n$:  write the Cantor set
as a decreasing intersection $K=\bigcap_{n}X_n$, where each  $X_n$ is the union of intervals one usually considers when describing
the Cantor set.  Then the inductive system formed by the algebras $C(X_n)$ with connecting maps
$f\in C(X_n)\to f|_{X_{n+1}}\in C(X_{n+1})$ has $C(K)$ as inductive limit and $\varphi _1$ is the map $\varphi $ described above.